# Ring homomorphisms map non units to non units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A ring homomorphism maps units to units.

I was wondering if it implies that it maps non units to non units. I tried to find a counter example because I think the answer should be no but couldn't find one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, what if one ring is a field and the other isn't?

Comment: What ring homomorphisms have you looked at? Off the top of my head, I think you have to try hard to find examples that *aren't* counterexamples: I think the only two classes that are "easy" to find are homomorphisms from a field, and the embedding from a ring into the polynomial ring over it.

Answer (score 3):

Every integral domain is embedded in a 'field of fractions' of its elements, so any such non-field will have a natural (injective) homomorphism to a field which fails this property.

An easy example is $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ with $f(m) := m$

Comment: This is not true. The ring has to be at least a domain for this to have any chance of being true, and then it is true. (And that assuming the ring is commutative. Without that hypothesis, things are quite more delicate...)

Comment: Your edit does not fix this. As I wrote, the ring has to be a domain for the map into its field of fractions to be injective (and the «field of fraction» of a non-domain has to be defined with care...)

Comment: There you go :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ah yes, I imagine you're quite correct. It's been a long time since I did the construction, and I forget at which point in the course we started assuming these things.

Answer (score 2):

Can you describe the ring morphisms $\mathbb C[x]\to\mathbb C$?

Can you describe the ring morphisms $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?